# ¿Cómo enviar parámetros acelerómetro via bluetooth con Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arduino

Quisiera saber cómo enviar los valores del eje 'x' y el eje 'y' del acelerómetro de mi móvil a través de `bluetooth` para que un sistema `arduino` los lea (mediante un hc-05) y lo procese para mover unos servos. Estoy utilizando `android studio` para hacer una app. Se cómo obtener los parámetros y mostrarlos en pantalla, pero me faltaría saber cómo enviarlos.

Comment: igual te ayuda separa las preguntas o reducir esta a una, 1) Quisiera saber cómo enviar......a través de bluetooth...para que un sistema arduino los lea. Y una vez consigas eso centrarse en lo siguiente, solo es una opinion.Saludos

Comment: igual esto te ayuda -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Is6pJyEv8s0 Saludos

Comment: podrias mirar esta respuesta pregunta para ver algo de codigo de los dos lados http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540754/send-data-from-arduino-to-android-app-via-bluetooth Saludos

Comment: @Angel, gracias por tus comentarios. En primer lugar, el vídeo ya lo vi y no me sirve debido a que la conexión arduino-bluetooth la hace a través de pc. Yo necesito que sea directamente de un dispositivo móvil al sistema arduino (Por eso estoy utilizando el programa de Android Studio para crear la aplicación.

Comment: En segundo lugar, lo que me gustaría saber es cómo identificar los parámetros del acelerómetro de dicho dispositivo móvil y/o convertirlos de tal manera que pueda transferir dicha información por bluetooth para que ya el sistema arduino los procese como corresponda. Me miraré detenidamente la respuesta pregunta que me has propuesto a ver si saco alguna idea. Muchas gracias de nuevo por tus sugerencias y por dedicarle tiempo.

Comment: @Sandydowns lee este post hasta el final. Se trata de un proyecto que trata de de cómo usar Android y gestionar el hardware con Processing vía Bluetooth muy bien documentado [ http://www.sistemasorp.es/2011/08/13/android-processing-bluetooth/ ]. Dentro del post, se hace referencia a este otro post que te va a gustar aun mas: [ http://www.akeric.com/blog/?p=1313 ] "Consultar datos del acelerómetro y el campo magnético del teléfono"

Comment: Bueno, hice algo parecido...un autito controlado por bluetooth usando android y arduino, en mi caso solo tenia que mover lls motores de un piente H, según sé al.arduino se le envian los datos en bytes es decir, cuando queria que el autito vaya a la derecha le enviaba una letra desde el android por decir la A, en el codigo del arduino tenia un procedimiento que evaluava los casos de letras que recibia, si la letra era A, activaba algun motor, si la letra era R activaba otros y asi...incluso le puse bocina y faros, existe un metodo en android para convertir las cadenas a bytes y luego enviarlos